# Twitter-oAuth-IPhone : Which function on Login Success : twits of followings

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, twitter-oauth, mgtwitterengine

I am using Twitter-oAuth-IPhone https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone

Login using this code

```
if(![twitterObj isAuthorized]){
    UIViewController *controller = [SA_OAuthTwitterController controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine:twitterObj delegate:self];
    if (controller){
        NSLog(@"twitter 2");
        [[self objectForKey:@"self"] presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES];
    }
}
```

I have 2 questions

- I want to do some code on login success and login fail.... in which function should I code
- Which function return me the my home page updates i.e twits of followings

**Amit Battan**

Comment: for 2nd question it is `getFollowedTimelineSinceID`

Comment: any answer for first part of question ..... `I want to do some code on login success and login fail.... in which function should I code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to do some code on login success and login fail.... in which function should I code
**- (void) storeCachedTwitterOAuthData: (NSString *) data forUsername: (NSString *) username**

Which function return me the my home page updates i.e twits of followings
**getFollowedTimelineSinceID**